# Can I mark a form as valid as a browser user?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am browsing Angular application in Chrome.
I can change classes of `input` elements by setting `ng-valid` manually.
I can even set `ng-valid` class on `form` element.
But internally, object of type `FormGroup` in the form does not change value of field `valid`.
Can I do it not programmatically (in a browser)?

Comment: Are you actually asking about security? If so, please re-frame your question in that vein. The short answer is that you should not depend on the front-end for security.

Comment: @isherwood, suppose an user can click on Submit button only when the form is valid. Is there any reason to check whether the form is valid in the click handler of Submit button? The button is enabled only when the form is valid.

Comment: Front end validation is a courtesy to users, to prevent having the back end kick out invalid data. The back end should be doing the same checks and maybe more than the front does. Never rely on your front end alone - a malicious user can just post the data using postman or similar, and extensions like EditThisCookie are a thing. (this may not be why you asked your question, of course, just wanted to mention it)